# What is causing the blank space to display?

Tags: html, css

I have this website I'm working on and hadn't noticed while I was building it but now I noticed a large white space to the right of the site?

I'm confused as to how this is happening.

I'm thinking it's from not specifying a width?

Could anyone help me with this?

The website address is www.mrsgrocery.com

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Is it me, or is that link broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replaced

```
   <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_32x32_style addthis_default_style" style="position:relative;top:9px;left:640px;width: 200px;">
```

add  width: 200px;

at  facebook twitter google+ icon  area

Comment: @xujinliang1227: what it was previously set?

Comment: @ShawnTaylor : Don't know what you mean, my English level to just English four levels

Comment: @xujinliang1227: I meant what was wrong with this code that you corrected.

Comment: @Shawn Taylor:Width is too big.

Comment: I hadn't set the any width at all for this div and it was causing the space. ty